# How to display it as title and value for the xpath

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Below is the xml.

```
<product_spec_group1>Device Compatibility</product_spec_group1>
<product_spec_identifier1>BluetoothCompat_HK_US</product_spec_identifier1>
<product_spec_value1/>
<product_spec_value1_language>de</product_spec_value1_language>
<product_spec_group2>General Specifications</product_spec_group2>
<product_spec_identifier1>Power Consumption</product_spec_identifier1>
<product_spec_value1>65W (maximum); 0.5W (standby mode)</product_spec_value1>
<product_spec_value2_language>de</product_spec_value2_language>
<product_spec_group3>Audio Specifications</product_spec_group3>
<product_spec_identifier1>Input Impedance</product_spec_identifier1>
<product_spec_value1>>10k ohms</product_spec_value1>
<product_spec_value3_language>de</product_spec_value3_language>
<product_spec_group3>Audio Specifications</product_spec_group3>
<product_spec_identifier2>Frequency Response</product_spec_identifier2>
<product_spec_value2>40Hz – 20kHz</product_spec_value2>
<product_spec_value3_language>de</product_spec_value3_language>
<product_spec_group3>Audio Specifications</product_spec_group3>
<product_spec_identifier3>Signal-to-Noise Ratio</product_spec_identifier3>
<product_spec_value3>>85dB</product_spec_value3>
<product_spec_value3_language>de</product_spec_value3_language>
<product_spec_group3>Audio Specifications</product_spec_group3>
<product_spec_identifier4>Drivers</product_spec_identifier4>
<product_spec_value4>Two Ridge and two Atlas transducers</product_spec_value4>
<product_spec_value3_language>de</product_spec_value3_language>
<product_spec_group3>Audio Specifications</product_spec_group3>
<product_spec_identifier5>Power</product_spec_identifier5>
<product_spec_value5>
Tweeters: 2 x 15 watts @ 1% THD Woofers: 2 x 30 watts @ 1% THD
</product_spec_value5>
<product_spec_value3_language>de</product_spec_value3_language>
<product_spec_group3>Audio Specifications</product_spec_group3>
<product_spec_identifier6>Input Sensitivity</product_spec_identifier6>
<product_spec_value6>250mV</product_spec_value6>
<product_spec_value3_language>de</product_spec_value3_language>
```

I want to display the output as
 
Device COmpatibility
Bluetooth  - value
General specifications
Power consumption - 65W (maximum); 0.5W (standby mode)
Audio specifications
Frequency response - 40hz -20khz
signal-to-Noise ratio - 85db
Drivers two ridge and two atlas transducers ....likw wise.

i have tried below. But it does not give desired output.

```
$i = 1;
        $spec_title = array();
        $spec_value = array();
        $j=1;
        $k=0;
        $l=1;
        foreach($xml->children() as $product_element)
        {


            if(trim((string)$product_element->getName())=='product_spec_group'.$l)
            {

                $key_value = trim((string)$product_element);
                $k++;
                $j=1;
                $x=0;
                $l++;


            }



            if($product_element->getName()=='product_spec_identifier'.$j)
            {       
            $x++;
            $spec_title[$key_value][$x]['product_spec_identifier'] = trim((string)$product_element);
            if(!strlen(trim((string)$xml->{'product_spec_value'.$j})))
            $j++;

            }
            if($product_element->getName()=='product_spec_value'.$j)
            {
                $spec_title[$key_value][$x]['product_spec_value'] = trim((string)$product_element);
                if(!strlen(trim((string)$xml->{'product_spec_value'.$j.'_language'})))
                $j++;

            }
            if($product_element->getName()=='product_spec_value'.$j.'_language')
            {
                $spec_title[$key_value][$x]['product_spec_language'] = trim((string)$product_element);
                $j++;
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found solution for this.This solves my requirement

```
$i = 1;
        $spec_title = array();
        $spec_value = array();
        $j=1;
        $k=0;
        $l=1;
        $product_spec_group_array = array('product_spec_group1',
        'product_spec_group2',
        'product_spec_group3',
        'product_spec_group4',
        'product_spec_group5',
        'product_spec_group6',
        'product_spec_group7',
        'product_spec_group8',
        'product_spec_group9',
        'product_spec_group10',
        'product_spec_group11',
        'product_spec_group12',
        'product_spec_group13',
        'product_spec_group14',
        'product_spec_group15',
        'product_spec_group16',
        'product_spec_group17',
        'product_spec_group18',
        'product_spec_group19',
        'product_spec_group20'
        );
        foreach($xml->children() as $product_element)
        {


            if(in_array($product_element->getName(),$product_spec_group_array))
            {


                $key_value = trim((string)$product_element);
                if($key_value == $key_old_value)
                {
                    $j++;
                }
                else {
                    $j=1;
                    $x=0;

                }
                $key_old_value = $key_value;

                $k++;
                $l++;
            }

            if($product_element->getName()=='product_spec_identifier'.$j)
            {       
            $x++;
            $spec_title[$key_value][$x]['product_spec_identifier'] = trim((string)$product_element);


            }
            if($product_element->getName()=='product_spec_value'.$j)
            {
                $spec_title[$key_value][$x]['product_spec_value'] = trim((string)$product_element);
            }
```